# Change `\textlnot` to something usable in math mode with `kpfonts`

Tags: math-mode, unicode, kpfonts

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

This is a formula: $¬¬p \implies p$

\end{document}
```

The output does not typeset the `¬` unicode symbol (NOT SIGN) and I get this warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textlnot invalid in math mode on input line 8
```

It seems that `kpfonts` is taking care of handling `¬` but it assigns to it a command that works in text mode (which seems a strange default since this is a mathematical symbol).

How can I redefine the symbol to something usable in math mode (*e.g.* `\lnot`) or, better, to make it expand to `\textlnot` in text mode and `\lnot` in math mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `¬` as `\textlnot` is done by `inputenc` with the `utf8` option, because `kpfonts` loads `textcomp` and `ts1enc.dfu` has

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AC}{\textlnot}
```

You can load `newunicodechar` and fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{¬}{\TextOrMath{\textlnot}{\lnot}}

\begin{document}

This is a formula: $¬¬p \implies p$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (making it active)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\catcode"00AC=\active
\def¬{\ifmmode\lnot\else\textlnot\fi}

\begin{document}

This is a formula: $¬¬p \implies p$

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, but since the `kpfonts` package already does something similar, I was asking rather how to plug into the same mechanism used by the package. Does the package simply make it active and redefines it as `\textlnot`? or is it something to do with the `inputenc` package and the handling of unicode characters?

Comment: @gigabytes I just grep'ed the source code of kpfonts.sty and could not find anything related to lnot. I would guess it is inputenc related, but I don't know. What's the problem with just redefining it? The output looks quite right.

Comment: no problem, I was just trying to understand what was going on under the hood.